# How many ways are there to arrange $n$ married couples in a line so that a husband and his wife are not together?

Tags: combinatorics

There are $2n$ people. There are $2n!$ ways to arrange them.

The number of ways to arrange them such that couples are always together is $n! \cdot 2^n$

How do you calculate the number of ways to arrange them such that no couples are together?

Comment: No, since it is possible that some couples are together while others are not.  See [Derangments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)